# CSS working in all browser but not in IE

Tags: html, css

I have one simple login page, where I am applying some of the css code as follows :

```
 div.loginheader {

        width: 100%;
        height: 25%;
        position: relative;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 0 auto;
        top: 6%;
        left: 6%;
      }
 img.center {
    display: block;

    padding: 0px;

  }
       td.caption
      {
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: Arial,Georgia,Serif;
        color: #ffffff;
        font-size:24px;
      }
```

With the following HTML Code :

```
<div class="loginheader">
         <table width="90%">
          <tr>
              <td width="20%" class="caption">
                  <img class="center" src="abc.png">
              </td>
              <td width="80%" class="caption">

                    Test Text
              </td>
            </tr>
           </table>
      </div>
```

But using above code, it's working perfectly in all the brwoser except IE. In IE the the positions and margins are destroying. My Web page looks as this
 [image: link]

in IE 7.

Any Help would be highly appreciated..

Comment: Also - I noticed you have a `td.center` class, but in the markup the only thing with `class="center"` is the `<img>` element. Is this intentional?

Comment: what do you mean works perfectly? can you send us a screenshot of how it looks in ff and in ie?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what exactly doesn't work in IE ? I also suggest you provide the context as well, because running the code exactly as you posted it does not give any information whatsoever.

Comment: Updated the question with screenshot of IE 7.

Comment: Try to design the page at run-time with IE developer toolbar, and then compare changes in other browsers, I agree with you that IE makes some different look while using width in %.

Comment: try taking 1% off the right column

Comment: @corroded can u elaborate, where exactly u r saying to taking off 1%?

Comment: <td width="80%" class="caption"> <-- here you can put 79% or better take 1% of each, so you can do 19% and 79%

Comment: Corroded is right. You're running into IE's inability to properly round numbers from percentages. The sum of your columns are 1 or 2 pixels wider than the total width, pushing the right content down.

Comment: You're problem is not unusual or unexpected. IE is the worst browser on the planet. Inept at best, it is 12 years behind all other browsers in modern standards and compliance. To help you, though, requires the complete markup or, preferably, a link to the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *In IE the the positions and margins are destroying*

Smells much like that IE is running in [quirks mode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html) which caused that the IE6/7 [box model bug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_box_model_bug) has manifested. Ensure that you're declaring/using the right doctype in *top* of the HTML page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

#### See also:

- [Activating browser modes with doctype](http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/)